# Why react-bootstrap text-center didn't work ? and why my HR auto center itself if i change the width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Hi guys so I'm trying to create front-end for my website using react-bootstrap and I try to change my hr width but it auto center itself, why is that ? and also i try to use className="text-center" from bootstrap to center things from my col but it didn't work, can anybody help me with that please ? I already import the bootstrap css but still didn't work.

here's my code:

```
      <Row className="aboutus regular">
        <Col className="aboutusleft" lg ="6" >
            <h1 className="semibold"> About Us</h1>
            <hr style={{width:'20%'}}></hr>

            <p>Diamond Hotel serves as an urban oasis for both discerning business and leisure travelers. Located in the heart of Samarinda and close to the most prominent culinary tourism object. The hotel itself possess a trendy design with attention to comfort, quality and value based accommodation. It features 75 modern rooms and suites with contemporary design environment to make you feel completely at home.</p>

            <button className="aboutbutton">Learn More</button>
        </Col>

        <Col className="aboutusright text-center" lg ="4">
          <img src="./img/Group4.png"></img>
        </Col>
      </Row>
```

My index.js (CSS bootstrap located):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It would help clarify what you're asking if you post what the current output looks like and what you want it to look like.

Comment: I want the className="text-center" help me to centered anything store inside that class, in my case it's an image and for the HR tag I want it to stay in the normal position, which is the left side not centered.

Comment: did any of your bootstrap class is working or having a problem with text-center class only

Comment: also give the margin: 0 to hr element, it will relocate to the left

Comment: only the text-center, I can use the other bootstrap class

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Col className="aboutusright mx-auto" lg ="4">
    <img src="./img/Group4.png"></img>
 </Col>
```

Please use "mx-auto" instead "text-center".